# Implement graph-like data structure in Rust

Tags: data-structures, rust, ownership

I have a data structure which can be represented as a unidirectional graph between some structs linked with link objects because links contain metadata.

It looks something like this:

```
struct StateMachine {
    resources: Vec<Resource>,
    links: Vec<Link>,
}
struct Resource {
    kind: ResourceType,
      // ...
}

enum LinkTarget {
    ResourceList(Vec<&Resource>),
    LabelSelector(HashMap<String, String>),
}

struct Link {
    from: LinkTarget,
    to: LinkTarget,
    metadata: SomeMetadataStruct,
}
```

The whole structure needs to be mutable because I need to be able to add and remove links and resources at runtime. Because of this, I cannot use the normal lifetime model and bind the resources to the parent struct's lifetime.

I understand that I need [to "choose my own guarantee"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/choosing-your-guarantees.html) by picking the appropriate type, but I'm not sure what's the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually, for a graph like structure, the simplest solution is to use an arena such as [`TypedArena`](https://crates.io/crates/typed-arena).

The lifetime of the nodes will then be only dependent on the lifetime of the instance of the typed arena they were created from, which will greatly simplify resource management.

**Warning**: avoid a scenario where you dynamically add/remove nodes to the graph, as the nodes will NOT be removed from the arena until said arena is dropped, so the size of the arena would grow, unbounded.

---

If you are in a situation where you will add/remove nodes at runtime, another solution is to:

- have a collection of `Resources`
- have the edges only indirectly refer to the `Resources` (not owners, and not borrowers either)

Two examples:

- `HashMap<ResourceId, (Resource, Vec<ResourceId>)>`
- `type R = RefCell<Resource>`, `Vec<Rc<R>>` and `Vec<(Weak<R>, Vec<Weak<R>>)>`

in either case, you are responsible for cleaning up the edges when removing a resource, and forgetting may lead to a memory leak and panics (when dereferencing) but is otherwise safe.

There are, probably, infinite variations on the above.

Comment: I add and remove many nodes and the application is a server process, so memory leaks are an issue. Do you know another solution? In the meantime I'll have a look at the other answer.

Comment: @Aragon0: I added another design idea where decoupling the resource and the references to others (not using a direct pointer), it requires more book-keeping but is safe.

Comment: This looks like a good idea! I can deal with more bookkeeping, as long as the whole thing is safe and reasonably fast.

Answer (score 40):

Modeling graph-like structures in Rust is not a simple problem.
Here there are two valuable discussions from Nick Cameron and Niko Matsakis (two main Rust developers at Mozilla.)

[Graphs and arena allocation](https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp/blob/master/graphs/README.md)

[Modeling Graphs in Rust Using Vector Indices](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/04/06/modeling-graphs-in-rust-using-vector-indices/)

Answer (score 20):

The simplest solution for a graph-like structure is to *use a library which models graphs*. [petgraph](https://crates.io/crates/petgraph) is a good choice:

```rust
use petgraph::Graph; // 0.5.1
use std::{collections::HashMap, rc::Rc};

struct Resource;

enum LinkTarget {
    ResourceList(Vec<Rc<Resource>>),
    LabelSelector(HashMap<String, String>),
}

struct SomeMetadataStruct;

fn main() {
    let mut graph = Graph::new();

    let n1 = graph.add_node(LinkTarget::LabelSelector(Default::default()));
    let n2 = graph.add_node(LinkTarget::LabelSelector(Default::default()));

    let _l2 = graph.add_edge(n1, n2, SomeMetadataStruct);
}
```

The guarantees that you have to choose here center around the member of `ResourceList`. I assume that you wish to have single-threaded shared immutable `Resource`s.

- if you need to share them across threads, use a `Vec<Arc<Resource>>`
- if they aren't shared, you can own them — `Vec<Resource>`
- if they need to be mutable, use a `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Resource>>>` (Or a `Mutex` or `RwLock` if also multithreaded)