# Multithreaded branch and bound search in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, dynamic-programming, lifetime

I am trying to solve a mathematical minimization problem using a branch and bound algorithm, in Rust. For simplicity, let's say that we're trying to find the objective value only.

### Functional

Solving the problem requires solving an easier version ("the relaxation"), which then may give rise to precisely two subproblems. Solving a relaxation takes a long time and needs to happen on a separate thread.

The difficulty is that a problem's subproblems are known only after the problem is solved. As such, the binary tree in which the problem and its subproblems live, grows during the computation. Moreover, the solving of a relaxation might result in nodes of the tree getting pruned. For each known problem, a sizable table has to be stored. Because of limited memory capacity, I want to search this tree in a depth-first order.

### Non-functional

Performance of the tree doesn't matter as much; the vast majority of the time will be spent solving the relaxations. I would like to avoid using manual relative references and similar constructs, and instead use Rust's toolbox of references to solve this problem. As a bonus, I'd like to capture the life-cycle of the problem-nodes in the type system:

1. The problem is known
2. It is being solved
3. The relaxation is solved and

   - If the problem turns out to be feasible:

     - If the objective value of the relaxation below a global maximum, the subproblems are computed
     - If not, the problem is marked suboptimal, further subproblems are irrelevant
   - If not, the problem is marked infeasible, further subproblems are irrelevant
4. Both subproblems are solved and only the objective value of this problem is stored

### Example of attempt

I've attempted several approaches, but I keep running into problems. My latest approach is best summarized by the definition of the node in the tree. The problem data is stored in the `Tableau`.

```
enum Node<'a, T, TP> {
    /// The problem to solve. Nothing is known.
    Undecided {
        parent: Option<rc::Weak<Self>>,
        depth: u64,
        tableau: Tableau<'a, T, TP>,
    },
    /// Being calculated
    ActiveCalculation {
        parent: Option<rc::Weak<Self>>,
        depth: u64,
        tableau: Arc<Mutex<Tableau<'a, T, TP>>>,
        sender_to_active_thread: Sender<PruneReason>,
    },
    /// The problem is solved, and the children (if any) should be created while this variant is
    /// being instantiated.
    NodeOptimal {
        parent: Option<Weak<Self>>,
        relaxation_value: f64,
        best_lower_bound: Cell<Option<f64>>,
        lower: Rc<Self>,
        upper: Rc<Self>,
    },
    /// This problem and all generated subproblems are solved.
    SubTreeOptimal {
        lower_bound: f64,
    },
    /// Pruned.
    Pruned(PruneReason), // e.g. SubOptimal, Infeasible
}
```

I tried to manage the tree with the main thread, while providing worker threads with an `Arc` to the problem data. The `sender_to_active_thread` field on the `ActiveCalculation` variant is used to terminate a calculation, when newly found information determines that the calculation could only yield a suboptimal result.

The problem with the above attempt is that I don't know how to update the tree once a solution is found. See below the code that fetches the next problem from the tree, hands it off to a thread, and processes the result:

```
let (solution_sender, solution_receiver) = channel();

    // Stop condition
    while !tree.finished() {

        let mut possible_next_problem = tree.next_problem();
        // Wait condition
        while active_threads == max_threads || possible_next_problem.is_some() {
            // Wait for a signal, block until a thread has terminated
            let (solved_problem, result) = solution_receiver.recv().unwrap();
            active_threads -= 1;

            let new_node = match result {
                None => Node::Pruned(PruneReason::Infeasible),
                Some((solution, objective_value)) => {
                    unimplemented!()
                }
            };
            tree.update(solved_problem, new_node);
            possible_next_problem = tree.next_problem();
        }
        // Assumed to be of `Undecided` variant
        let next_problem = possible_next_problem.unwrap();

        let solution_sender_clone = solution_sender.clone();
        let (termination_sender, termination_receiver) = channel();
        *next_problem = next_problem.undecided_to_active_calculation(termination_sender);
        let pointer_to_problem_in_tree = next_problem.clone();
        if let Node::ActiveCalculation { tableau, .. } = *next_problem {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let result = solve_in_separate_thread(&mut *tableau.lock().expect("Should be of variant `Undecided`"),
                                                      termination_receiver);
                solution_sender_clone.send((pointer_to_problem_in_tree, result)).unwrap();
            });
        } else { panic!("Should be of variant `ActiveCalculation`.") };
    }
```

The compiler tells me that just moving an `Arc<Node>` to the thread (and sending it to the main thread again) requires that `Node` and all its fields are `Sync`.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/vandenheuvel/rust-lp/blob/branch_and_bound/src/algorithm/simplex/branch_and_bound/mod.rs).

Comment: It appears that you've put a lot of effort into your question, but unfortunately it does not seem like a good fit for Stack Overflow (yet?). I see two main problems: (1) it seems overly broad as it seems to want us to write large portions of your code for you (2) what code you have provided isn't a [MCVE]. My advice is to drastically reduce your problem to something manageable. I bet that you don't need 5 enum variants to reproduce the core problem; there should be a function, etc. We should be able to reproduce your problem using the question itself, no links. Links are good for addl context.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: You may be interested in [Implement graph-like datastructure in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34747464/155423) or [How do I express mutually recursive data structures in safe Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36167160/155423).